# BERT sentence embeddings: how to obtain sentence embeddings vector

Tags: keras, nlp, embedding, word-embedding, sentence

I'm using the module `bert-for-tf2` in order to wrap BERT model as Keras layer in Tensorflow 2.0 I've followed your guide for implementing BERT model as Keras layer.
I'm trying to extract embeddings from a sentence; in my case, the sentence is "Hello"

I have a question about the output of the model prediction; I've written this model:

```
model_word_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
                tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,), dtype='int32', name='input_ids'),
                bert_layer
])

model_word_embedding .build(input_shape=(None, 4))
```

Then I want to extract the embeddings for the sentence written above:

```
sentences = ["Hello"]
predict = model_word_embedding .predict(sentences)
```

the object predict contains 4 arrays of 768 elements each:

```
print(predict)
print(len(predict))
print(len(predict[0][0]))
...

[[[-0.02768866 -0.7341324   1.9084396  ... -0.65953904  0.26496622
    1.1610721 ]
  [-0.19322394 -1.3134469   0.10383344 ...  1.1250225  -0.2988368
   -0.2323082 ]
  [-1.4576151  -1.4579685   0.78580517 ... -0.8898649  -1.1016986
    0.6008501 ]
  [ 1.41647    -0.92478925 -1.3651332  ... -0.9197768  -1.5469263
    0.03305872]]]
4
768
```

I know that each array of that 4 represents my original sentence, but I want to obtain one array as the embeddings of my original sentence.
So, my question is: How can I obtain the embeddings for a sentence?

In BERT source code I read this:

> For classification tasks, the first vector (corresponding to [CLS]) is used as the "sentence vector." Note that this only makes sense because the entire model is fine-tuned.

So I have to take the first array from the prediction output since it represents my sentence vector?

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 2):

We should use [CLS] from the last hidden states as the sentence embeddings from BERT. According to the BERT paper [CLS] represent the encoded sentence of dimension 768. Following figure represents the use of [CLS] in more details. considering you have 2000 sentences.

```
#input_ids consist of all sentences padded to max_len. 
last_hidden_states = model(input_ids)
features = last_hidden_states[0][:,0,:].numpy() # considering o only the [CLS] for each sentences 
features.shape
# (2000, 768) dimension
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, very useful. Do you know why running a single row of data through the model always results in the same CLS token, no matter which row I pass to it? Running multiple works fine, but a single one always gives the exact array `[ 0.35013607, -0.5340336 ,  0.28577858, ..., -0.03405955,
         -0.0165604 , -0.36481357]]`

Comment: I think you should be careful about using [CLS] as sentence sentence representation: https://bert-as-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/section/faq.html#why-not-use-the-hidden-state-of-the-first-token-as-default-strategy-i-e-the-cls