# BERT - Extracting CLS embedding from multiple outputs vs single

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I'm using transformers TFBertModel to classify a bunch of input strings, however I'd like to access the CLS embedding in order to be able to rebalance my data.

When I pass a single element of my data to the predict method of my simplified bert model (in order to get the CLS data), I take the first array of the `last_hidden_state`, and voila. However, when I pass in more than one row of data, the shape of the output changes as expected, but it seems the actual CLS embedding (of the first row that I first passed in) changes too.

My dataset contains the input ids and the masks, and the model:

```
from transformers import TFBertModel

model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased', trainable=False, num_labels=len(le.classes_))

input_ids_layer = Input(shape=(256,), dtype=np.int32)
input_mask_layer = Input(shape=(256,), dtype=np.int32)

bert_layer = model([input_ids_layer, input_mask_layer])

model = Model(inputs=[input_ids_layer, input_mask_layer], outputs=bert_layer)
```

Then, to get the CLS embeddings I just call the predict method and dig into the result. So for the first row of data (data_x[0] being the input ids, and data_x[1] being the masks)

`output1 = model.predict([data_x[0][0], data_x[1][0]])`

```
TFBaseModelOutputWithPooling([('last_hidden_state',
                               array([[[ 0.35013607, -0.5340336 ,  0.28577858, ..., -0.03405955,
                                        -0.0165604 , -0.36481357]],
                               
                                      [[ 0.34572566, -0.5361709 ,  0.281771  , ..., -0.03687727,
                                        -0.01690093, -0.35451806]],
                               
                                      [[ 0.34878412, -0.5399749 ,  0.28948805, ..., -0.03613809,
                                        -0.01503076, -0.35425758]],
                               
                                      ...,
```

My understanding is that the CLS representation of the sentence is the first array of the last_hidden_state i.e:

```
lhs1 = output1[0]

lhs1.shape
>> (256, 1, 768)

cls1 = lhs1[0][0]

cls1
>>[0.35013607 ... -0.36481357]` (as above)
```

So far so good. My confusion arises when I now want to obtain the first 2 of the CLS embeddings from my dataset:

```
output_both = model.predict([data_x[0][:2], data_x[1][:2]])
lhs_both = output_both[0] # last hidden states

lhs_both.shape
>> (2, 256, 768)

cls_both = lhs_both[0][0] # I thought this would give me two CLS arrays including the first one above
```

Inspecting `cls_both`:

```
array([[[ 0.11075249, -0.02257648, -0.40831113, ...,  0.18384863,
          0.17032738, -0.05989586],
        [-0.22926208, -0.5627498 ,  0.2617012 , ...,  0.20701236,
          0.3141808 , -0.8650396 ],
        [-0.22352833, -0.49676323, -0.5286081 , ...,  0.23819353,
          0.3742358 , -0.69018203],
        ...,
        [ 0.5120927 , -0.09863365,  0.7378716 , ..., -0.19551781,
          0.45915398,  0.22804889],
        [-0.13397002,  0.1617202 ,  0.15663634, ..., -0.511597  ,
          0.3959382 ,  0.30565232],
        [-0.14100523,  0.22792323, -0.15898004, ..., -0.2690729 ,
          0.4730471 ,  0.18431285]],

       [[-0.20033133, -0.08412935, -0.0411438 , ...,  0.34706163,
          0.1919156 , -0.08740871],
        [-0.12536147, -0.44519228,  1.2984221 , ...,  0.07149828,
          0.7915938 ,  0.08048639],
        [ 0.4596323 , -0.3316555 ,  1.2545322 , ..., -0.02128018,
          0.5344383 ,  0.32054782],
        ...,
        [-0.54777217,  0.23129587,  0.5007771 , ...,  0.70299244,
          0.27277255, -0.2848366 ],
        [-0.49410668,  0.37352908,  0.8732239 , ...,  0.6065303 ,
          0.152081  , -0.9312557 ],
        [-0.33172935, -0.35368383,  0.5942321 , ...,  0.7171531 ,
          0.24436645,  0.08909844]]], dtype=float32)
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this - my expectation was to see the first rows CLS `cls1` contained within `cls_both`, but as you can see, the first row in the first sub array is different. Can anyone explain this?

Furthermore, if I run **only** the second row through, I get exactly the same CLS token as the first, despite them containing totally different input_ids/masks:

```
output2 = model.predict([data_x[0][1], data_x[1][1]])
lhs2 = output2[0]
cls2 = lhs2[0][0]


cls2
>>
[ 0.35013607, -0.5340336 ,  0.28577858, ..., -0.03405955,
         -0.0165604 , -0.36481357]]

cls1 == cl2 
>> True
```

#### Edit

[BERT sentence embeddings: how to obtain sentence embeddings vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330597/bert-sentence-embeddings-how-to-obtain-sentence-embeddings-vector)

Above post explains that `output[0][:,0,:]` is the correct way to obtain exactly the CLS tokens which makes things easiers.

When I run three rows through, I get consistent results, but any time I run a single row through, I get the result shown in `cls1` - why does this not differ each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there was an issue with the shape of the sliced `data_x` that you passed in.

Since you did not specify the shape of `data_x`, I first attempted to replicate it below:

```
text = ['a sample text','another text', 'the third text']

bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
tokenizer_output = bert_tokenizer(text, return_tensors='np', max_length=256, padding='max_length')

data_x = np.array([
    tokenizer_output['input_ids'], 
    tokenizer_output['attention_mask']
])

print(data_x.shape)
```

where the shape of `data_x` is `(2, 3, 256)`.

**data_x[0][0] is not the correct way to slice**

For your first row of data, you prepared the input_ids and attention_mask by slicing it using `data_x[0][0]` and `data_x[1][0]`, the shape of your input_ids and attention_mask becomes `(256,)`

```
print(data_x[0][0].shape) # (256,)
print(data_x[1][0].shape) # (256,)
```

while the TF model expects the input shape of `(batch_size, 256)` for both `input_ids_layer` and `input_mask_layer`. Note that the `shape` argument supplied to `Input` does not include the batch_size, as quoted from its documentation [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/input/) : `shape: A shape tuple (integers), not including the batch size.`.

In fact, when I attempt to pass the input `[data_x[0][0], data_x[1][0]] # Both with shape (256,)`, I received the following warning from Tensorflow:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 256) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_3'), name='input_3', description="created by layer 'input_3'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 1).
...
```

**The correct way to slice the input data**

You should be slicing them without changing the tensor dimension, so that your input_ids and attention_mask remains in the form of `(batch_size, 256)`

```
# For first sentence only
input_1 = [data[0][0:1], data[1][0:1]] # Shape : (1,256) (1,256)

# For second sentence only
input_2 = [data[0][1:2], data[1][1:2]] # Shape : (1,256) (1,256)

# For first and second sentence
input_12 = [data[0][:2], data[1][:2]]  # Shape : (2,256) (2,256)
```

And after passing the above data to your model, you will get the CLF embeddings using `output[0][:,0,:]` as described in the link you shared.

You can confirm that the embeddings for the 1st and 2nd sentences are the same, whether you pass in `input_1`, `input_2` or `input_12`:

```
output1 = model.predict(input_1)
output2 = model.predict(input_2)
output12 = model.predict(input_12)

ihs1 = output1[0] # Shape : (1, 256, 768)
ihs2 = output2[0] # Shape : (1, 256, 768)
ihs12 = output12[0] # Shape : (2, 256, 768)

cls1 = ihs1[:,0,:] # Shape : (1, 768)
cls2 = ihs2[:,0,:] # Shape : (1, 768)
cls12 = ihs12[:,0,:] # Shape : (2, 768)

# Check that cls1 is exactly the same as cls12[0]
print((cls1 == cls12[0]).all()) # True

# Likewise, cls2 is exactly the same as cls12[1]
print((cls2 == cls12[1]).all()) # True
```

Hope this clears thing up for you. Always remember to check the input and output shape of the model when you are in doubt.